# How to get hidden column in DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm able to get index 2 and 3 of my DataTable while looping through all the checked items. My problem is I can't get the column ID that was set to visible = false.

```
<table id="myTable"class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input name="myCheckbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox-select-all" type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
manageTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: base_url + 'rule/fetchCategory',
    data: function(d) {
      d.category = categoryFilter;
    }
  },
  'columnDefs': [{
    'targets': 0,
    'searchable': false,
    'orderable': false,
    'className': 'dt-body-center',
    'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
      return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
    }
  },
  {
  "targets": [1],
  "visible": false
    }]
});
    
//Function on form submit

var rows = [];
manageTable.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
var row = $(this).parent().parent();

if (this.checked) {
  var data = [];
  $(row).find("td").each(function(i, obj) {
    if (i == 2) {
      data.push($(this).text());

    } else if (i == 3) {
      data.push($(this).text());
    }

  })
  data.push($("#category").val());
  rows.push(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't iterate over the html of the table because the hidden column obviously isn't in the HTML DOM.

Use datatables functions for this purpose.

First, use [row selection plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) for selected rows.

Then, iterate over row's data with `myTable.rows({selected:true}).data()`

Full working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              
              <script
              src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
              
              <script
              src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.4/js/dataTables.select.js"></script>
              
              <LINK href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
              
              <LINK href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.4/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
              
              
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Checkbox</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Checkbox</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var myTable = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    myTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
          columnDefs: [ 
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets:   0
            },
            
            {
                visible: false,
                targets:   1
            }
            
        ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        }
    });
    
    
});

</script>
```

And then, you can iterate over row's data with:

```
myTable.rows({selected:true}).data()
```

[image: Example]